# using the value held by a key in an array to query the database in another function

Tags: php, mysql

I have this function that searches a table on the database and it works perfectly. Now I have a new function that is meant to pick the value of the key held by the array in the first function and query another table in the database. It doesn't seem to be working
Here's my code:

```
public function getTransformers() {
    $deb = array(); //I made this global at the top of the class

    $trans = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM transformers');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($trans)) {
        $den[$row['codes']]["name"] = $row["name"];
        $den[$row['codes']]["codes"] = $row["codes"];
        $den[$row['codes']]["previous_reading"] = $row["previous_reading"];
        $den[$row['codes']]["current_reading"] = $row["current_reading"];
        array_push($this->deb, $den);

    }
    $this->getBookcodes($this->deb);
}

 public function getBookcodes($transformers) {
     $trans =mysql_query("SELECT book_code FROM transformer_book_codes WHERE transformer_codes = '$key'");
    $books = [];
    foreach ($transformers as $item) {
       echo $this->getTransformers('name')["codes"];
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you tell me what 'doesn't seem to be working?'

Comment: It doesn't return the values on the "transformer_book_codes" table.  Because I intend to return the values stored in one of the columns on that table using the "code" from the transformer table

Comment: never use 'not working' when asking a question (here or off line) always describe the exact error. Never use mysql_* functions. Read up on sql JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Did you have something like this in mind?

```
public function getBookcodes($transformers) {
    $books = [];
     foreach ($transformers as $key => $value) {
        $trans =mysql_query("SELECT book_code FROM transformer_book_codes WHERE transformer_codes = '".$key. "'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($trans)) {
            $books[] = $row;
        }
    }
}
```